# How to send output from one terminal to another without making any new pipe or file

Tags: command-line

I am just fooling around on my terminal (Gnome terminal). I was wondering is there a way to send output of one terminal to another without having to make a new file or pipe.

for example: on first terminal I run `ls` and want its output to be displayed on second terminal (with or without using any command on second)

Comment: what do you have? Did you try something? Can you give some examples?

Comment: @tachomi on first terminal I run `ls` and want its output to be displayed on second terminal (with or without using any command on second)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If both terminals belong to the same user, you can send your output to the virtual device that is used as the particular terminal's tty.

So you can use the output from `w`, which includes the TTY information, and write directly to that device.

```
ls > /dev/pts/7
```

(If the device mentioned by `w` was pts/7)

Another option is to use the number of a process that is connected to that device. Send your output to `/proc/<process number>/fd/1`.

```
ls > /proc/5555/fd/1
```

Assuming the process number that you found that runs in that terminal is 5555.

Note that this direct write is only allowed if **the user that attempts to write is the same user that owns the other terminal**.

Comment: I dont get `/dev/pts/7` or similar with `w` command, but second way works for me

Comment: @edwardtorvalds The `/proc/XXX/fd/1` is generally a soft link to the base device. Try using `ls -l /proc/XXXX/fd/1` and see what it is pointing to. Does it have any relation to what appeared in the `w` command?

Comment: I am not relating `w` command with `/proc/XXX/fd/0` I am relating `w` command with `/dev/pts/7`

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I am saying that they are connected as `/proc/XXX/fd/1` is supposed to be a soft link to whatever device the `w` command displays. What is the output of `ls -l` on it?

Comment: TTY information can also be found in the output from `tty` (only current) or `who` (all).

Comment: `echo $$` provides the pid (`XXX`) of the current terminal.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `write` command.

As @MelBurslan commented, if write permission is off, first execute:

```
 $ mesg y
```

From `man mesg`

> OPTIONS
>
> y Allow write access to your terminal.

Usage of write:

```
$ write username tty
```

e.g. Send `ls` output to other terminal.

```
$ w
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user     :0       :0               08:15   ?xdm?   7:37   0.25s init --user
user     pts/0    :0               08:19    1.00s  0.09s  0.01s w
user     pts/12   :0               08:50   54.00s  0.03s  0.03s bash

$ ls | write username pts/12
```

Comment: on arch linux, in gnome terminal, output of `w` command is `edward   tty2      19:53    6:05   2:48  23.12s firefox` and if I write `ls | write edward tty2` I get no output but a beep sound

Comment: also if I try it on tty5 (ctrl + alt + 5) I get error `you have turned write permission off`

Comment: that was typing error on this site

Answer (score 15):

I found a similar method.

**On first terminal**:

```
 $ tty
 /dev/pts/0
 $ <no need to run any command here, just see the output>
```

**On second terminal**:

```
$ ls > /dev/pts/0
```

***Now you get the output on first terminal***

Comment: `tail -f` instead of `cat` could be useful

Comment: @tachomi actually there is no need of any command to read the output

Answer (score 9):

Use the `tty` command in each terminal to identify them:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0

$ tty
/dev/pts/1
```

Assuming these TTYs, to redirect the first's stdout to the second, run this in the first terminal:

```
exec 1>/dev/pts/1
```

> Note: Now **every command output** will show on pts/1

To restore default behavior stdout of pts/0:

```
exec 1>/dev/pts/0
```

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqVQxehmfuo) for a demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

you can write to the terminal's TTY; for example:

in terminal 1:

```
$ tty 
ttys000
```

in terminal 2:

```
$ tty
ttys029

$ exec &> >(tee >(cat >&/dev/ttys000))
ls
```

Output will show in both terminals in real-time even as you type.

Works on linux and macOS. The macOS TTY path is `/dev/{number}` while on Linux it's `/dev/pts/{number}`

Comment: executing `exec &> >(tee >(cat >&/dev/ttys000))` does not exists, making it impossible to type.

Comment: @EdwardTorvalds on linux the `tty` will be something like `/dev/pts/0`

Comment: yeah, that is what I used to test your code

Comment: @EdwardTorvalds what command doesn't exist?

Comment: your command `exec &> >(tee >(cat >&/dev/pts/1))`. No control key combination (ctrl+c) work. I have to kill the terminal to exit

Answer (score -2):

You can use `wall` also:

```
$ wall "Message here"
```

Comment: you might wanna describe it in detail. I don't understand anything from this

Comment: You definitely do *not* want to use `wall` (short for "write all"), as it writes to every logged-in tty session, including the one you're sending from.  Instead, using `write` allows a specific tty to be declared.