# In what format does piped output get sent and received from one command/program to another?

Tags: linux, pipe, command, executable

When a command is piped to another command in what way or in what format does the piped output exist/get sent? Is it a temporary file? Is it a string? And how does the command that receives the piped output decode/read that output?

---

*Example:*

```
echo "Someone string" | ./program | tail
```

---

Does the program "`program`" receive the output of `echo` as a file?
How would the program read in that input?

Comment: The part about temporary files depends from whether one is asking about very old versions of Unix.  (-:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450900/5132

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470767/how-does-a-program-know-what-to-read-in-a-pipeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes as a bit stream. That's how it's sent and how it's received. The interfaces are *file descriptors* (or *handles*). A simple file is also handled that way.

See:

- [Standard streams on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)
- [File descriptor on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)

Comment: So (correct me if I'm wrong) if I wanted a program (that I wrote) to read in the output of a command/program/process (let's say that simply prints to standard out a shape, say a square);  **"`./print_square | ./program `"**  ; From my program, I would need to read the piped output from standard-in as a string of bytes (a bit string) ? And from that string, I'd need to parse and figure out how to understand that string of bytes to be a square shape ?

Comment: I like your succinct answer, but would it be more accurate to call it a byte stream, since that's the smallest unit that can be written ?

Comment: @Lion Yes, the program you write should read from standard input, you can develop it by typing at the terminal or redirecting stdin from a file with a "canned" input. Then use it in a pipe stream later to read the output of the previous command.

Comment: @XTian I'll keep it bit, as I mean the bit level, as opposed to higher level communication. And this could be in octets of bits or other sets, depending on architecture.

Comment: @Lion Yes, it's always about parsing. There are standards like ASCII or UTF-8 for text, but there are always single bits underneath and that has to be remembered.

Answer (score 5):

A pipe is a form of redirection (transfer of standard output to some other destination) that is used in Linux and other Unix-like operating systems to send the output of one command/program/process to another command/program/process for further processing. The Unix/Linux systems allow stdout of a command to be connected to stdin of another command. You can make it do so by using the pipe character ‘|’.

Pipe is used to combine two or more command and in this the output of one command act as input to another command and this command output may act as input to next command and so on. It can also be visualized as a temporary connection between two or more commands/ programs/ processes. The command line programs that do the further processing are referred to as filters.

This direct connection between commands/ programs/ processes allows them to operate simultaneously and permits data to be transferred between them continuously rather than having to pass it through temporary text files or through the display screen.
Pipes are unidirectional i.e data flow from left to right through the pipeline.

Syntax :

```
command_1 | command_2 | command_3 | .... | command_N
```

Example :
Listing all files and directories and give it as input to more command.

```
$ ls -l | more
```

The `more` command takes output of `ls -l` as its input. The net effect of this command is that the output of `ls -l` is displayed one screen at a time. The pipes act as a container which take output of `ls -l` and giving it to `more` as input. This command does not use a disk to connect standard output of `ls -l` to standard input of `more` because pipe is implemented in the main memory.
In terms of I/O redirection operators, the above command is equivalent to the following command sequence.

```
$ ls -l -> temp
more -> temp (or more temp)
[contents of temp]
rm temp
```

More [1](http://www.westwind.com/reference/os-x/commandline/pipes.html), [2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/piping-in-unix-or-linux/), [3](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mamrak.1/CIS762/pipes_lab_notes.html)

Answer (score 4):

`./program` receives the output of `echo` as a file, namely the [standard stream file `/dev/stdin`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)).  Demo:

```
echo foo | wc -c
echo foo | wc -c /dev/stdin
```

Outputs:

```
4
4 /dev/stdin
```

Note:  a stream file is somewhat different from a file stored on a disk.  We can [access data randomly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) in a regular file, but not in a [streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing)) file.  It's like the difference between a CD player and radio playing a song.  On the CD player we can rewind, fast forward, seek, and skip songs.  The radio just outputs (or streams) whatever the broadcaster is sending *right now*.

Where is the stream stored?  The OS stores it in a temporary [data buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer), the size of which varies between OSes.  See [How big is the pipe buffer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer)

---

On a lower level, the OS uses [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), not filenames.   File descriptors are just a stack of numbers, for which each [process identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) has its own stack.  Linux also allows accessing the `/dev/stdin` stream, (which is always file descriptor *"0"*), that way:

```
echo foo | wc -c /proc/self/fd/0
```

Output:

```
4 /proc/self/fd/0
```

---

One more Linux abstraction can be seen with the `realpath`util:

```
realpath /dev/stdin /proc/self/fd/0
```

Output (on the current terminal on my system):

```
/dev/pts/2
/dev/pts/2
```

The letters `pts` stand for [***P**seudo **T**erminal**s***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devpts).  That last `2` number will always vary between terminals, so it's not a reliable name, but those numbers can be used for tricks like: [How to send output from one terminal to another without making any new pipe or file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261531/how-to-send-output-from-one-terminal-to-another-without-making-any-new-pipe-or-f).